# Push and keep the details locally with Git

Tags: git

I have this local Git repository in which I developed a new feature. This work is not fully tested and I let this branch quite messy since I am the only developer on this particular feature.

Here is what I basically have locally:

```
               v feature
  b1--b2--b3--b4
 /             \
a1--a2--a3--a4--a5
             ^   ^ master
             origin/master
```

When I want to push `a5`, all the `b` commits will be pushed because `a5` has two parents. However I don't want to share all the details of my messy work with the community. On the remote, I would like to get this

```
a1--a2--a3--a4--a5
             ^   ^ master
             origin/master
```

where `a5` is the result of my work.

If I do not want to keep all the details, I can simply `cherry-pick` as rebased version of my `feature` branch into my master. Unfortunately this will not work since I want to keep the intermediate commits just for me.

How can I achieve this? Is this a bad workflow?

Comment: How about creating a new commit using all the changes introduced with cherry-picking`b1---b4` on top of master? The history will be preserved as tree of local branch tip commit.

Comment: Yeah, this is a solution. So I shall never merge `feature` onto `master`

Comment: "Unfortunately this will not work since I want to keep the intermediate commits just for me."

Aren't those intermediate commits on your feature branch? Why would they be lost if you are only cherry-picking and rebasing on your master branch?

Comment: Well, I don't understand what's wrong with plain merge, but it's up to you (and your team) to decide. BTW, you can always use `commit --amend` or stash-related techniques to clean up your commits.

Comment: Create a third branch, squash the commit there, then merge the third one against master. Though, as other pointed out, I do not get the issue: if you don't need the commits on master, you don't need them for yourself neither, so I would just clean up my branch before merging. Up to you. As a side note, I would not keep a straight history on master, in case you want to rollback the merge later on, `git merge --no-ff` will help you!

Comment: In general, I feel it is best to "own up" to your own commit history and let it stand as a boring and un-built part of the record (b1..b4). For me, this prompts me to do better the next time. This is a psychological opinion, not a technical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge feature into master with `git merge --squash`, your next `git commit` will create `a5` with all your changes merged in, but without a pointer back to `b4`. So your repo will look like this:

```
               v feature
  b1--b2--b3--b4
 /             
a1--a2--a3--a4--a5
                 ^ master
```

Then you can push master without any of the b commits getting pushed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your `feature` onto `master` first, then `git rebase -i HEAD~5` to squash all the commits into a single one, then force push with `git push -f origin`.

Read more about squashing [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)